# How is the size of a PNG file determined?

Tags: png

The image properties for this image say that the width and height are respectively 340 pixels and 471 pixels. The bit depth is 24 bits. My understanding was that this means that the value associated with each pixel is encoded using 24 bits. So I expected the file size to be around 471 * 340 * 24 = 3843360 bits  = 480420 bytes =480 KB. But then one of the image properties says the size of the file is 9.98 KB. Why the big difference?

I am reading the images into a convolutional neural network where I need to supply the input shape.

Below is a screenshot of image properties

[image]

Below is a screenshot of actual image:

[image]

Comment: PNGs are filtered and compressed on disk.

Answer (score 0):

The PNG image format is designed to support [lossless data compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression). The file size you calculated is completely uncompressed, just raw image data. To save disk space, the file is compressed, and given your example of the image, this can be done very effectively  because most of the image is exactly the same color.